# Marionette Layout object to render tab content

Tags: marionette

I have a region in which I need to have a tabbed view (simple) however if I want the tab content to be differently layout - not sure how to achieve it. I can create different layout with multiple region and corresponding view, but how do I attach this to tab content, given that applyout can only be attached to region? Or can this be attached to one of the div of tab-content using $el?? Need some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand your question.. But here goes.

I have implemented a navigation component where I can pass a tabsCollection and region. It will set up a region for the content and a list of tabs above it. When a tab is clicked it will fire the callback on the model in the tabsCollection which can be used to display what ever content you want.

There are more complex ways to handle this to allow for caching of a tabs content. But basically using a Backbone collection for the tabs with their own function for displaying content will do the trick.